# Get SRC from embed code and put it in own iframe, because it needs to go that way

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I have a submit form for adding videos on my wordpress site that I create this code...

```
<?php

$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true );
$search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
$replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);

?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This code will take youtube url and change it to embed code and add src to iframe, also i can post src source from embedable source and it will also work, but...

What I want to do now is if in field I put

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

take `https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid`from code above and put it in `$url`.

When I try it with existing code, my output is...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="&lt;iframe width=" iframe-embed"="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Update:
I found the way how embed codes will be extracted its via this function...

```
<?php

$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true );
$search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
$replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url2        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);
$url3        = preg_match('~iframe.*src="([^"]*)"~', $url2, $result);
$url4        = $result[1];

?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url4; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now, I need to combine first function and seconds one, php code should check if its embed code that has SRC value to use preg match for src andf extract src, else it should use first function.

Something like check if SRC value exists, and than use...

```
$url3        = preg_match('~iframe.*src="([^"]*)"~', $url2, $result);
$url4        = $result[1];
```

otherwise...

```
$url4        = $url2;
```

Comment: Okay, so what problem are you having?

Comment: When I try it, my src output is<iframe width=.. broken..

Comment: @MLL please [edit] your question and make sure the problem description is in the text of the question. Comments can be deleted, and questions should be stand-alone.

Comment: Ok, it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true );
$search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
$replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url2        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);
$url3        = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$url2.'" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$url4        = preg_match('~iframe.*src="([^"]*)"~', $url3, $result);
$url4        = $result[1];

?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url4; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```